# Excel converting a specified string to a specifed integer in the next column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range, vba

EDITED

I need to create a string array which will write itself out in its integer equivalent.

For instance I want to declare string Z001 = 30

So if I in cell J1 write Z001, K1 will be set to 30.

How can i declare such list, so it will automatically change?

Comment: Take a look at the Worksheet_Change Event, it should be able to do what you are asking :)

Comment: Of course it's possible, however giving any more useful hints based on your question isn't really possible. Please give us more detail to understand your problem. Please also share what have you tried so far, this site is not about solving entire problems, but going people get stuck. And very important: Don't answer in a comment, but edit your question.

Comment: This would be possible if you would make a table, matching the strings to numbers and then referring to them either by a `VLOOKUP` or by a `INDEX`+`MATCH` combination.

Comment: Where have you declared "string Z001 = 30"?  My interpretation is that in one place you have a list of such strings. You then want to enter "Z001" into your worksheet and have a macro scan the list for "Z001" to find the value that the macro is to copy into the next cell.

Comment: I have not declared it. That is what i want to do. I want a macro with fixed values of some strings and then automatically put those values in the next column when writing the string

Comment: Unless you include a person's name preceeded by @ in your comments, they are not told you have replied. You can write `Const Z001 As String = 30` or `Dim Z001 As String: Z001 = 30`.  The first makes Z001 a constant which cannot be changed. The second makes Z001 a variable that can be changed as necessary.  Alternatively you could record these values in a hidden worksheet. If you want the value 30 to appear as soon as the user types Z001, you need to use a Worksheet Change event routine to monitor the cells where the user might type Z001.